# How enable EBS encryption with AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-ebs

I'm trying to set up an ECS cluster with EC2 instance type. My requirement is to encrypt the EBS volumes used by the ECS cluster. But, I couldn't see an option to select encrypted EBS during the ECS cluster creation. What I'm only seeing is an option to provide EBS volume size under instance configuration:
[image]

Is there any other way to implement EBS encryption in an ECS cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating instances using the ECS console, you can create an them using EC2 console/CLI/CloudFormation/etc and join the created instances to the ECS cluster. That way you have full control of the instance options and contents, including specifying EBS encryption.

You will need to use an Amazon ECS optimised AMI to launch the instances, and you can join the cluster by adding the following to UserData:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ECS_CLUSTER=your_cluster_name >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

Full details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html

Comment: Thanks for this info. So, in ECS if we terminate an EC2 instance, a new instance will get automatically spawned, right? With this setup, does that work, or do we need to create auto-scaling groups for that?

Comment: No, it's not automatic. You will need to use an autoscaling group if you're manually managing the instances and you want that behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the accepted answer is not an optimal solution, since it's neither scalable, nor resilient.

An alternative would be to create a `CloudFormation` template, and use `AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup` based on a custom `AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate`, where you can specify the properties of the underlying EC2 instances, including encrypted EBS volumes. The UserData scripts on the EC2 instances shall register themselves with your ECS cluster.

```yaml
ECSLaunchTemplate:
  Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
  Properties:
    LaunchTemplateName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-lt
    LaunchTemplateData:
      ImageId: !Ref ImageAMI
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
          Ebs:
            DeleteOnTermination: True
            Encrypted: True
            VolumeType: gp2
            VolumeSize: 30

ECSAutoScalingGroup:
  DependsOn: ECSCluster
  Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
  Properties:
    LaunchTemplate:
      LaunchTemplateId: !Ref ECSLaunchTemplate
      Version: !GetAtt ECSLaunchTemplate.LatestVersionNumber
```

Comment: This will not work if the drive is created in the Task. This is necessary as the task would have it's own requirements that are different from other tasks.

Comment: @acivic2nv The question was about ECS cluster based on EC2 with encrypted EBS volumes. Task definition has nothing to do with EBS volume. Tasks (Docker containers) are executed on the underlying hardware (EC2 + EBS). All tasks scheduled on this particular EC2 instance will have encypted EBS.

Answer (score 0):

I have scoured the internet to get this to work and followed all documentation. I found that at least another person has this issue and has a possible work around by manually creating the volumn in docker. See:
https://github.com/rexray/rexray/issues/1363

Another option, of which I just confirmed works, you can enable encryption by default for EBS volumes in the zone you are in.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSEncryption.html